# Distribute Python application with C modules for different platforms

Tags: python, windows, linux, macos, software-distribution

I want to distribute a Python application with compiled C binaries for several platforms like Windows, Linux, and MacOS X. I don't want to force the user to compile anything or install a specific version of a certain library (like PIL) to avoid compile troubles or version conflicts with Linux package management.

What is the best way to cross compile the application? Is it possible to compile for MacOS without having a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191942/distributing-pre-built-libraries-with-python-modules), the answer seems to be to use the `package_data` argument to `setup.py` if you're using distutils. Before calling `setup()`, you should build the `package_data` dictionary depending on the platform you detected, e.g. with `platform.platform`.

It is generally possible to build `gcc` as a [cross-compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler). This specific question [has been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693952/how-to-compile-for-os-x-in-linux-or-windows).